# how do i get input from user into list<int> correctly and then print out the size and elements?

Tags: c++, list

I'm trying to fill a list of type int with input from the user. the input will be separated by white spaces. then I would like to print out the size of the list after all elements have been entered, then print out all the elements of the list. I'm not sure why this doesn't work.:(

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
  list<int> one;

  cout << "Enter the elements of the list: ";

  while (!cin == NULL)
  {
      one.push_front(cin);
  }

  cout << "List size = " << one.size();

  for (auto itr = one.begin(); itr != one.end(); itr++)
  {
      cout << *itr << endl;
  }

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, post the exact error your getting

Comment: This is what happens in the console, i cant wrap my head around why the size is off or why its skipping the first element when printing..              
                                                                                                            Enter the elements of the list : 1 2 3 4 g
List size = 44
3
2
1
Press any key to continue . . .                                                                                This is after i made the changes

Comment: check my answer below. but your not using endl.  Thats probably the main thing that is wrong

Comment: Also, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll be sure to do that from now on. Btw have you ever done anything with a permutation sort algorithm?

Comment: I have, its been a bit but once you learn these things its easy to remember them

Comment: I'm trying to set up a program to do a permutation sort on a list of ints inputted from the user. I'm just a little unsure of  how the algorithm steps through the process, if that makes sense.. Do you know of any references or animational videos that would help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155374/discussion-between-kman123-and-legman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to insert into your list

```
while (cin >> input) 
        one.push_front(input);
```

and to print try this which is roughly what you alreadyhave

```
for(list<type>::iterator iter = one.begin(); iter != one.end(); iter++){
   cout<<*iter<<endl;
}
```

Size should work.
Make sure to add in endl to your output
  cout << "List size = " << one.size() << endl;

Also here is the docs for list.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

Let me know if you need more information

Comment: the size isnt off

Comment: you need to add endl at the end of the size

Comment: No problem, it happens to the best of us